# How to get folder metadata in oracle UCM

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle-ucm

I have a requirement where I need to get the folder meta data information in my custom filter.

Normally I get the content metadata information by using the

binder.getLocalData();

I am not getting how to retrieve the complete metadata of a folder?

Please let me know if anyone aware of it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Folder metadata is know as `xCollection`. Also here are the list for the Folder Services: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e11011/c08_folders002.htm#i1082113